# Вывод значения из списка

Tags: java, android

Требуется, чтобы при выборе в контекстом меню для выбранного города подставлялась ссылка в Glide (доп. библиотека для отображения гиф). Контекстное меню при длинном тапе вызывается, но далее после выбора из списка дело не идет.

В идеале хотелось бы, чтобы **по кнопке** на экране вызывался список и выбирался город, но пока только контекстное меню смог вызвать и составить в нем список.

Вот мои наработки:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView ImageView;
    private Button getRadar;
    private TextView city;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getRadar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getRadar);
        ImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
        city = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.city);

        registerForContextMenu(city);

    }


    final int brest = 1;
    final int moskva = 2;
    final int minsk = 3;


    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.city:
                menu.add(0, brest, 0, "BREST");
                menu.add(0, moskva, 0, "MOSKOW");
                menu.add(0, minsk, 0, "MINSK");
                break;
        }

    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case brest:
                Glide.with(this).load("http://site.ru/1.gif").asGif().into(ImageView);
                break;
            case moskva:
                Glide.with(this).load("http://site.ru/2.gif").asGif().into(ImageView);
                break;
            case minsk:
                Glide.with(this).load("http://site.ru/3.gif").asGif().into(ImageView);
                break;

        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: контекстное меню не совсем подходит для вашей задумки и лучше не торопиться а изучить новое что то для себя, а потом пробовать применять.. тут лучше воспользоваться списком, а уж каким, вам решать.. либо это будет диалог, либо listview либо recyclerview например

Comment: Если картинка на том же экране, что и выбор города, то уместнее всего в качестве селектора использовать [`Spinner`](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/spinner.php). Имена экземпляров класса принято писать с маленькой буквы `ImageView imageView;` (в [lowCamelCase](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) стиле)/ Имена ресурсов так же принято писать с маленькой буквы `R.id.imageView`

Comment: @pavlofff, я вчера пробовал `Spinner`, да, удобно, но у меня не получилось передать в Glide соответствующую городу ссылку. Не могли бы Вы привести хотя бы самый простой пример, как это реализуется?

Comment: Вы не можете связать выбор в спиннере с изображением, которое надо показать?

Comment: @pavlofff, да =(

Comment: Ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, что нужно (и что не нужно) делать, когда кто то [ответил на ваш вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код может выглядеть примерно так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    boolean isRun;
    final String[] city = {"Moscow", "Minsk", "Brest", "Selected city .."};
    final String[] imageURL = {"http://site.ru/1.gif","http://site.ru/2.gif","http://site.ru/3.gif"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, city){
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
              int count = super.getCount();
              return count > 0 ? count - 1 : count;
          }
        };
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setSelection(adapter.getCount());
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (isRun) Glide.with(view.getContext()).load(imageURL[position]).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image).into(imageView);                   
                isRun = true;
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

В массив `city` помещаем названия городов, в массив `imageURL` соответствующие им изображения. Так как загрузка изображения занимает некоторое время, лучше всего поставить локальную картинку-заглушку на время загрузки, которую вам нужно выбрать самостоятельно и поместить в папку *res/drawable/* - в примере картинка с именем *placeholder_image*.

**UPD** Для того, чтобы при старте ничего не отображалось в `ImageView`, вводим флаг `isRun`, который срабатывает после выбора значения в спиннере.
Так же применен небольшой хак, чтобы при первом старте появлялось не название города в спиннере, а предложение его выбрать. Для этого добавляем в конец списка городов текст с предложением выбора и немного переопределяем адаптер, чтобы эта надпись не появлялась в выпадающем списке, а в спиннере при старте назначаем эту запись для отображения.

Для работы с интернетом, чтобы загрузить картинку, необходимо в `androidManifest.xml` добавить разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: большое Вам спасибо, пример работает, все наглядно! Скажите пожалуйста, а можно ли чтобы `.placeholder` не отображался при запуске приложения? А то получается еще ничего не выбрано, а loading на `imageView` уже отображен.

Comment: @Pollux Дополнил ответ

Comment: и еще раз Вам огромное спасибо!!! Очень помогли, сам бы не осилил. Может Вы, как специалист, посоветуете какой либо толковый ресурс/уроки для изучения java новичку?

Comment: @Pollux По обучению у меня [примерно такие рекомендации](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=159318&view=findpost&p=33907185) (сейчас все упомянутые там книги имеют более свежие редакции). Что касается непосредственно реализации алгоритмов - этому труднее научиться, здесь нужно умение логически мыслить и умение объяснить "машине", что ты от нее хочешь. Лучшая практика, после изучения теории (уверенного владения языком Java и понимание возможностей фреймворка Android) тут - изучать чужой код и разбираться, что именно там происходит, на том же Github его в избытке.

Comment: Интернет-ресурсы я бы не рекомендовал для обучения, так как они, в отличие от книг, не дают целостную картину по предмету, а как правило, разбирают по одному упрощенному примеру, сосредоточенному непосредственно на нем. Потом появляется такая проблема, что кусочки понятны, а как это работает друг с другом совершенно не ясно. Вообще по интернет-ресурсам (в качестве дополнительного чтения и более детального разбора по конкретным узким темам) - уроки Климова и startandroid.ru